# App router. How to catch-all pages requests in Nextjs 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

In Nextjs 12, with old Pages router I could write `pages/[...urlParts]/index.js`, and that would catch pages routes only (exactly what is needed). But now in Nextjs 13 I use their new App router, and my `app/[...urlParts]/page.js` route catches everything, including internal Nextjs requests like `/_next/static/css/app/ReactToastify.css.map`.

Any possibility to use my pages handler for everything BUT specific urls? Maybe here is some way to tell Nextjs to use the default handler for `_next/...` service links, but to keep my catch-all segment for pages?

Right now I use `/app/pages/[...urlParts]/page.js` structure, but that is a temporary solution, as I don't need the `pages/` part in my page url.

Maybe I should clarify my goal more. I'm working on a project that generates pages based on the url and the database data. So I need to have the opportunity to:

1. "catch-all" every possible route (except for api/..., _next/... and so on). I need to keep the default Nextjs handler for all the exceptions.
2. parse the provided url
3. search my database for the related data
4. generate the page and return the generated page result

Also I need to use some App router possibilities (like partial pages with separate caching), so I cannot normally switch to the old Pages router.

Comment: It works properly with Next 13.5

Answer (score 0):

To catch everything but specific urls (`_next/...`).

Create a route like this:

```
app/[...urlParts]:(?!_next/.*).*$
```

This will match everything that does not start with `_next/`.

To create the folder:

```
mkdir -p app/[...urlParts]:\(!_next\)
```

You can also achieve that by creating middleware.

```
function urlVerifier(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.startsWith('_next/')) {
    return next();
  }

  next();
}
```

Register the middleware Nextjs application.

```
module.exports = {
  middleware: [urlVerifier],
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you provide an example project? I cannot achieve the "route name" part. For example, I cannot create a folder with name "app/[...urlParts]:(?!_next/.*).*$" like you provided.

Comment: Please look at the updated question description.

Comment: I can't share the project because it is secret. Although I already updated my answer to create the folder,

Comment: Also, if you are unable to create the folder, you can use the second step (using middleware) concept.

Comment: I cannot use my middleware for a full-featured pages generation. I cannot create that folder even through different terminals, as there is a syntax error in that command.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Next.js to the latest version. I have tested it with Next.js 14.1 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually, It's OK with 13x version now, just minor patch-update. WTF was that...